# Adjust width to parent's width and truncate when higher

Tags: css

I have a panel with information and above it there's additional information displayed, but I'd like it to be subtle and a one-liner, so when the text that's contained in it is wider than the parent's width, it should be truncated.

[See jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvpwe15d/1/); this is a mock of what I am after.

This is the HTML for that extra information:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="extra-information">
    <span>Information</span> –
    <span>When this is too long it should be truncated</span>
  </div>
  <div class="main">Main panel</div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS I am trying so far:

```
.main-container {
  width: 350px;
  // ...
}

.main {
  // ...
}

.extra-information {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: inherit;
  max-width: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Check it out in another [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvpwe15d/2/).

Comment: You're first jsfiddle link is broken.

Comment: don't comment it, fix it. I fixed it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `text-overflow: ellipsis` with `overflow: hidden` in CSS

---

### text-overflow

The `text-overflow` property specifies **how overflowed content that is not displayed should be signaled to the user**.

Other possible values for this property are:

- **clip** : Default value. Clips the text
- **ellipsis** : Render an ellipsis ("...") to represent clipped text
- **string** : Render the given string to represent clipped text

---

### overflow

The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box.

This property specifies **whether to clip content or to add scrollbars when an element's content is too big to fit in a specified area**.

**Note**

The overflow property only works for **block-level elements**.

```css
.main-container {
  width: 350px;
}

.extra-information {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="extra-information">
    <span>Information</span> –
    <span>When this is too long it should be truncated</span>
  </div>
  <div class="main">Main panel</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it includes an actual explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```css
.main-container {
  font-family: Calibri, serf;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.main {
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.extra-information {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: inherit;
  max-width: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="extra-information">
    <span>Information</span> –
    <span>When this is too long it should be truncated</span>
  </div>
  <div class="main">Main panel</div>
</div>
```

Just added `overflow: hidden;`.