# Bootstrap4 navbar : truncate item to parent width

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to have a one-line navbar with a centered text element that can be arbitrary long that I need to truncate to leave space for others elements that are around.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghdtycbL/).

What I have looks like

```
Back    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
[Button]                                                                              Yadda yadda
```

Whereas I'd like to have :

```
Back  [Button]        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...           Yadda yadda
```

I've tried [Adjust width to parent's width and truncate when higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301071/adjust-width-to-parents-width-and-truncate-when-higher) but it's based on the parent container having a fixed width which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flexbox has an issue with minimum width. [`min-width: 0;`](https://dfmcphee.com/flex-items-and-min-width-0/)

- Note that I added `.flex-nowrap` to the `navbar`.
- Note that I added `.mw-100.text-truncate` to the `.nav-item`.

```css
.min-width-0 {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light flex-nowrap" id="navbar-top">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto no-expand">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/" role="button">Back</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item px-10">
      <a href="/" class="btn btn-secondary" role="button" hx-get={% url 'score_switch_compact' %} hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-target="#strips-container"><span class="material-icons md-24 vcenter">button</span></a>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-expand min-width-0">
    <li class="nav-item mw-100 text-truncate">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto no-expand">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/" role="button">
       Yadda yadda
      </a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

For centering your text element, you can style the two `navbar-collapse` elements as `flex: 1 0 0%`. That will cause the elements on the ends to grow equally, centering your text. To limit the amount of space for the text element, you can apply a width to the div (I used 70% on small screens, which works for displays down to 320px wide, after which the toggler wraps to the next line, and 50% on larger screens).

```css
.w-70 {
    width: 70%;
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    .flex-lg-1-0-0 {
        flex: 1 0 0% !important;
    }

    .w-lg-50 {
        width: 50% !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="navbar-brand w-70 w-lg-50 text-center text-truncate order-lg-1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
    </div>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1 navbarSupportedContent2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent flex-lg-1-0-0" id="navbarSupportedContent1">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link ml-2 ml-lg-0" href="#">Back</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" style="padding-top: 0.375rem">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Button</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent flex-lg-1-0-0 order-lg-2" id="navbarSupportedContent2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link ml-2 ml-lg-0" href="#">Yadaa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link ml-2 ml-lg-0" href="#">Yadaa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link ml-2 ml-lg-0" href="#">Yadaa</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">
            Center
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I did revise your version a little:

- I added a `navbar-toggler` button for smaller displays. Your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghdtycbL/) used `navbar-expand-lg` but did not include a toggle.
- The text element was styled as a `nav-item`, but there didn’t seem to be any benefit, so I changed it to have the text element styled as `navbar-brand`. Also, I start the text item on the left for small screens and then switch it to the middle for larger screens.
- There’s a link styled as a button. If it doesn’t take the user to a different page, it’s easiest to use a button, rather than a link (better for screen readers).

Comment: thanks for the detailled answer, I will try your suggestions